# The command migration did not execute

Tags: python, django

I have a challenge here. I am currently building an application,and I tried to add my app to the settings,in this way :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

In the model,here is the code :

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Initially I used this command in the terminal

```
cd myproject
manage.py migratrate
```

Here is the output: Apply all migrations: admin,auth,contenttypes,sessions
Running
migrations:No migrations to apply.
Having defined my database in the model,I used the following command.Please,how do I fix this?
Note that I am a beginner in Python and Django

Comment: Which app contains`Question` and `Choice` model

Comment: You need to run `manage.py makemigrations polls` first to create the migrations. If you're working through [tutorial 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models), then be careful not to miss out any steps.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think I saw your previous question where you mentioned that you deleted the migrations and then tried to start again. Is that correct? Because it can explain the error that you are now seeing.

Comment: Sorry! I did not let you know that I had already run the command, manage.py makemigrations polls. The output: No changes detected in app 'polls'

Comment: No! I did not delete the migrations

Comment: ok, sorry, then can you run this command and show output? - `python manage.py showmigrations`

Comment: ok,l will try it

Comment: In the INSTALLED_APPS other apps were shown except the polls apps output:[no migration

Comment: This is what I did in the project settings: 
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: In response to Shafik: They are both in the model app, from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: Please show the layout of your project files. In particular, check that your `Question` and `Choice` models are in the `polls/models.py`. If there is a `polls/migrations/` directory, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the `polls/migrations/__init__.py` file and directory exists. If the polls app is registered correctly in INSTALLED_APPS and the model is registered correctly but the migration file is not created, the next thing to check is to check if the migration directory is normal. Django checks if the `__init__.py` file exists in the migrations folder, so if it doesn't exist, it won't generate a migration file.

the polls app without `polls/migrations/__init__.py`:

[image: the polls app without polls/migrations/__init__.py]

the polls app **with** `polls/migrations/__init__.py`:

[image: the polls app with polls/migrations/__init__.py]

Comment: Thank you all. According to Youngminz, I did all earlier than your suggested solution,I realized that in my command I did not include "python" it was suppose to be "python manage.py makemigrations." Anyways,I appreciate you all for your contributions.